# Cisco Packet Tracer - I Lose Connection To Switch When I Switchport a Host Port

Tags: cisco

I am stuck on this very last little piece of building a fully functioning network. I am using a Server switch which is connected to two Client switches.

I have set up Vlans and trunked where I needed to. After thinking I was done (the left side of the network) I noticed the connection between the two Client switches and each of their two corresponding Hosts arent connected. I have been trying to isolate the problem, and I believe I have.

The problem occurs immediately after I type

```
:- int f0/4 ( this is port which is conneted to the computer)
:-switchport mode access
:-switchport access vlan 20 ( this port will go into vlan 20 with this command)
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

This happens again is I attempt to switchport access int f0/5 (Host2), and also with int f0/6 and f0/7.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network design and belongs on [networkengineering.se]

Answer (score -1):

You need put more details about the ports you are using in the design.

Remember you need interconnect the switches using a trunk mode ports and a subinterface tag in the router to enable the intervlan routing.